# Does new windows emoticons/emoji use UTF8 or another encoding?

Tags: mysql, windows, encoding, character-encoding

Windows 10 has built in support for emoticons by pressing **windows key+period** like so: 
When storing these in a mysql database using `utf8_general_ci` encoding/collation, they turn into squares.

Is there an encoding type which will allow these emoji to be stored or is there some other workaround for allowing users to utilise these smileys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`utf8` in mysql is buggy. You should use `utf8mb4`.**

Changing the table and text columns to `utf8mb4` encoding & `utf8mb4_general_ci` collation will allow them to store emoticons and other special characters.

Note that `utf8mb4` uses *up to* 4 bytes to store each character vs *up to* 3 bytes for `utf8`. This is efficient however and uses the minimum space needed to store each character. (See first comment below)

More info here: https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434

Comment: That's partially wrong.  It's _up to_ 3 (or 4) bytes.  Any characters that fit in utf8 will take the identical amount of space in utf8mb4.  More specifically, English will take only 1 byte per character in either charset.

Comment: Good link.  That guy knows (or envisions) some of MySQL's history that I had not heard.

Comment: Another takeaway:  Never use `CHAR` in place of `VARCHAR`.  (I'll make exceptions for places where Ascii is appropriate -- country_code, postal_code, UUID, MD5, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @Rick. I've updated the answer with your info. Good to know!